# Putting textbox values in data bounded gridview textbox (in all the rows )

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
<title>Create Docket</title>
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
var tb1 = document.getElementById('txtVehicleNo'); 
var tb2 = document.getElementById('txtVehicleNo1'); 
tb1.value = tb2.value; 
</script> 
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function Check_Click(objRef) { 
//Get the Row based on checkbox 
var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode; 

//Get the reference of GridView 
var GridView = row.parentNode; 

//Get all input elements in Gridview
var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
//The First element is the Header Checkbox
var headerCheckBox = inputList[0];

//Based on all or none checkboxes
//are checked check/uncheck Header Checkbox
var checked = true;
if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i] != headerCheckBox)
{
if (!inputList[i].checked) {
checked = false;
break;
}
}
}
headerCheckBox.checked = checked;

}
function checkAll(objRef) {
var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
if (objRef.checked) {
inputList[i].checked = true;
}
else {
if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
row.style.backgroundColor = "#C2D69B";
}
else {
row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
inputList[i].checked = false;
}
}
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body style="height: 451px; width: 860px">
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
 <div>
 <asp:GridView ID="gvAll" runat="server" 
 AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial" 
 Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
 HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"
 OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" PageSize = "10" Height="30px"     Width="341px">
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" 
 AutoPostBack = "true" OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged"/>
 </HeaderTemplate> 
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)" 
 AutoPostBack = "true" OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBox_CheckChanged" />
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField> 
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "DocketNo" HeaderText = "DocketNo" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "Date" HeaderText = "Date" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "BranchCode" HeaderText = "BranchCode" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "To" HeaderText = "To" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "PKTS" HeaderText = "No of pkg" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "ActWt" HeaderText = "ActWt" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "ChargeWt" HeaderText = "ChargeW" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "Description" HeaderText = "Description" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
<asp:BoundField DataField = "Remarks" HeaderText = "Remarks" 
HtmlEncode = "false" />
<asp:BoundField DataField = "Mode" HeaderText = "Mode" 
HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "ChallanNo" HeaderText = "ChallanNo" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "VehicleNo" HeaderText = "VehicleNo" 
HtmlEncode = "false" />
<asp:BoundField DataField = "ChallanDate" HeaderText = "ChallanDate" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "RChallanDate" HeaderText = "RChallanDate" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField = "FromHub" HeaderText = "FromHub" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField = "ToHub" HeaderText = "ToHub" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
</Columns> 
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B" />
</asp:GridView> 

 <br />
 <table border="1">
<tr>
 <td>
 <asp:Label ID="lblMode" Text="Mode" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <br />
 <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownMode" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem>Air</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem>Surface</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Rail</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
 </td>
```

This is the textbox which I'm using to put the value of vehicle number into the GridView gvSelected

```
 <tr>
 <td>
 <asp:Label ID="lblChallanNo" Text="Challan No." runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtChallanNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>

 <td>
 <asp:Label ID="lblLHCNo" Text="LHCNo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLHCNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
 <td>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <asp:Button ID="FindLHCNo" Text="Find" runat="server"     OnClick="FindLHCNo_Click" />
 </td>
 <td>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

 </td>

 <td>
 <asp:Label ID="lblLHCDate" Text="LHC Date" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLHCDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>

 </tr>
 </table>
 <br /> 
 <p align="center">
 <asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" Text="Update Challan"     OnClick="Update_Click" /> </p>
<asp:GridView ID="gvSelected" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial" 
Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" EmptyDataText = "" >
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DocketNo"
 SortExpression="DocketNo">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDocketNo" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("DocketNo") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date"
 SortExpression="Date">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField> 

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BranchCode"
 SortExpression="BranchCode">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBranchCode" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("BranchCode") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To"
  SortExpression="To">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("To") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PKTS"
 SortExpression="PKTS">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPKTS" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("PKTS") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ActWt"
 SortExpression="ActWt">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtActWt" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("ActWt") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ChargeWt"
 SortExpression="ChargeWt">
   <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtChargeWt" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("ChargeWt") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description"
 SortExpression="Description">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="50px"
Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'
ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks"
 SortExpression="Remarks">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("Remarks") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mode"
 SortExpression="Mode">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtMode" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("Mode") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ChallanNo"
 SortExpression="ChallanNo">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtChallanNo" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("ChallanNo") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VehicleNo"
 SortExpression="VehicleNo">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtVehicleNo1" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("VehicleNo") %>'
 ReadOnly="false" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ChallanDate"
 SortExpression="ChallanDate">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtChallanDate" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("ChallanDate") %>'
 ReadOnly="false" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RChallanDate"
 SortExpression="RChallanDate">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtRChallanDate" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("RChallanDate") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FromHub"
 SortExpression="FromHub">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromHub" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("FromHub") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ToHub"
 SortExpression="ToHub">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtToHub" runat="server" Width="50px"
 Text='<%# Bind("ToHub") %>'
 ReadOnly="true" ForeColor="Blue"
 BorderStyle="none" BorderWidth="0px">
 </asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 </Columns>
</asp:GridView> 
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$      ConnectionStrings:amitpandeyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     [BranchCode], [Date], [DocketNo], [To], [PKTS], [ActWt], [ChargeWt], [Mode],     [ChallanNo], [VehicleNo], [ChallanDate], [Description], [RChallanDate],     [Remarks], [FromHub], [ToHub] FROM [CreateDocket]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
 </div>

 </form>
</body>
</html>

C# Code
public partial class FNC : System.Web.UI.Page
{

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
 BindPrimaryGrid();
 BindSecondaryGrid();
 }
 }
 private void BindPrimaryGrid()
 {
 string constr =         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["amitpandeyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 string query = "select * from CreateDocket";
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
 gvAll.DataSource = dt;
 gvAll.DataBind();
 }

 protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
 {
 GetData();
 gvAll.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
 BindPrimaryGrid();
 SetData();
 }

 private void GetData()
 {
 DataTable dt;
 if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
 dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
 else
 dt = CreateDataTable();
 CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gvAll.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");
 for (int i = 0; i < gvAll.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
 if (chkAll.Checked)
 {
 dt = AddRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);
 gvAll.Rows[i].Visible = false;
 }
 else
 {
 CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk");

 if (chk.Checked)
 {
 dt = AddRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);
 gvAll.Rows[i].Visible = false;
 }
 else
 {
 dt = RemoveRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);
 }
 }
 }
 ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = dt;
  }

 private void SetData()
 {
 CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gvAll.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");
 chkAll.Checked = true;
 if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
 {
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
 for (int i = 0; i < gvAll.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
 CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk");
 if (chk != null)
 {
 DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("DocketNo = '" + gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "'");
 chk.Checked = dr.Length > 0;
 if (!chk.Checked)
 {
 chkAll.Checked = false;
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }

 private DataTable CreateDataTable()
 {
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("DocketNo");
 dt.Columns.Add("Date");
 dt.Columns.Add("BranchCode");
 dt.Columns.Add("To");
 dt.Columns.Add("PKTS");
 dt.Columns.Add("ActWt");
 dt.Columns.Add("ChargeWt");
  dt.Columns.Add("Description");
  dt.Columns.Add("Remarks");
  dt.Columns.Add("Mode");
  dt.Columns.Add("ChallanNo");
  dt.Columns.Add("VehicleNo");
  dt.Columns.Add("ChallanDate");
  dt.Columns.Add("RChallanDate");
  dt.Columns.Add("FromHub");
  dt.Columns.Add("ToHub");
  dt.AcceptChanges();
  return dt;
  }

  private DataTable AddRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
  {
  DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("DocketNo = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
  if (dr.Length <= 0)
  {
  dt.Rows.Add();
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["BranchCode"] = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Date"] = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["DocketNo"] = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["To"] = gvRow.Cells[4].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["PKTS"] = gvRow.Cells[5].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ActWt"] = gvRow.Cells[6].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ChargeWt"] = gvRow.Cells[7].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Description"] = gvRow.Cells[8].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Remarks"] = gvRow.Cells[9].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Mode"] = gvRow.Cells[10].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ChallanNo"] = gvRow.Cells[11].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VehicleNo"] = gvRow.Cells[12].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ChallanDate"] = gvRow.Cells[13].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["RChallanDate"] = gvRow.Cells[14].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["FromHub"] = gvRow.Cells[15].Text;
  dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ToHub"] = gvRow.Cells[16].Text;
  dt.AcceptChanges();
  }
  return dt;
  }

  private DataTable RemoveRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
  {
  DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("DocketNo = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
  if (dr.Length > 0)
  {
  dt.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
  dt.AcceptChanges();
  }
  return dt;
  }

  protected void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  GetData();
  SetData();
  BindSecondaryGrid();
  }

  private void BindSecondaryGrid()
  {
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
  gvSelected.DataSource = dt;
  gvSelected.DataBind();

  }
 }
```

I want to put the value of txtVehicleNo, which is outside the GridView gvSelected, into the bounded textbox field 'txtVehicleNo1' in all the rows of column VehicleNo of the GridView gvSelected.

Comment: On which event ? `OnLoad` of GridView or `OnClick` of a button ?

Comment: Please localize the problem, format it well and ask your question. In this case you will have better chance someone to answer you.